# IP routing to virtual network interfaces in guest OS

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm running VirtualBox 5.0.16 r105871 and have an Ubuntu VM running as a guest. VB has created 2 interfaces Adapter 1 (NAT) and Adapter 2 (Host-Only). This seems to correspond with interfaces eth0 & eth1.

My application Docker, has created a new network subnet within the VM which looks like this:

```
      br-9721ebff63d3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:8E:12:02:02  
      inet addr:172.20.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:8eff:fe12:202/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:928 (928.0 B)  TX bytes:1124 (1.0 KiB)
```

So my question is, how do I make this network visible outside of the VM ?

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to ping this ip from outside VM? 
it should reply. If it's replying than it's visible outside VM. 
For example, I have a computer from LAN with Windows_7 (ip: 10.0.255.10). Inside the LAN I also have a linux server (ip 10.0.255.1, not the DNS, just another computer with DHCP). Inside linux server, I also have VirtualBox with an openSuse machine. Both the network cards from VM, are set to bridged.
After VM starts, I can ping the ip of VM and also transfer files without any other settings.

Try and set the interfaces Adapter 1 (bridged adapter), and if needed set an ip your range.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was really simple in the end.

`sudo route -n add 172.17.0.0/16 "boot2docker ip"`